# How to concatenate multiple log files from multiple EC2 servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, nginx

So I'm running nginx on three EC2 servers all in different locations (US, EU, Asia). I want to execute a perl script every day on the joined log files (each EC2 holds an nginx log in /var/log/nginx/access.log).

It seems Amazon's CloudWatch has some similar abilities but then again I'm reading about pushing each log to a S3 location. What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Is it necessary you don't want to use S3? Or you want to use CloudWatch for this?

Comment: @error2007s I really don't mind what way, just looking for a solution

Comment: And are you using a ELB?

Comment: @error2007s no it's just different ec2 instances in different locations

Answer (score 1):

I have been amazed at the logs cost, performance and search capabilities of log aggregator services like [PaperTrail](https://papertrailapp.com/) for these kinds of problems.

We have 30 instances of all types running Windows with Nxlog configured on each. anytime we spin up an instance, its logs are immediately captured by the paper trail syslogd service. I cannot imagine running cloud services with some log aggregator.

The searching and archiving is great. Papertrail has a free plan 100 MB/month, 48 hour search time, and 7 day archiving.

Disclaimer: Not related to Papertail, just a happy customer.